# Maximum function nesting level of '100'

Tags: php, laravel

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no Laravel (ao recuperar uma senha):

> Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

A solução que encontrei foi adicionar esta linha no autoload.php

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 500);
```

E tudo funcionou.

Mas minha dúvida é, o que é isso e porque preciso alterar?

Por que ele gera esse erro?

Obrigada

Comment: Buscando na internet soluções parecidas encontrei essa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor. Uma explicação dada é que a extensão do xdebug limita a pilha no máximo 100 empilhamentos de ponteiros. Você pode aumentar a quantidade de empilhamento ou desabilitar no php.ini se vocè não utiliza essa extensão.

Comment: Mas na prática, significa que essa requisição que esta dando erro, está tentando fazer o que que chega a passar de 100?

Comment: Para cada chamada de função, é salvo o endereço de retorno na pilha, quando a função dá um return ele volta para a linha que a função foi chamada, pegando da pilha a ultima posição armazenada. Mas você deve possuir uma função que está chamando ela várias vezes e ultrapassando o tamanho máximo de 100 endereços de memória armazenados. Você pode utilizar uma explicação de como funciona uma pilha (Stack) com base na linguagem C: http://www.cprogressivo.net/2014/05/Pilhas-Stack-em-C-O-Que-E-Como-Implementar-Tutorial-C-Estrutura-de-Dados.html

Assembly também da uma explicação muito boa.

Comment: E a solução que encontrei é recomendada?

Answer (score 1):

É recomendada caso você não tenha como alterar a lógica da função para que ela diminua a quantidade de recursões. Porém, esta solução também depende da análise de impacto de performance e consumo de memória de sua aplicação/servidor/infraestrutura.

Isto quer dizer, antes de você assumir esta como a solução definitiva, seria interessante reavaliar o código nos pontos em que a exceção é lançada, caso realmente já esteja otimizado, mantenha a configuração.

Mas, realmente, usando Laravel algumas vezes me deparei com a necessidade de definir em 500 esta configuração, principalmente por causa de pacotes extras que geram muitas recursos com o xdebug ligado. Porém, utilizo esta configuração apenas em desenvolvimento e ambiente de testes, em produção não mantenho o xdebug ligado, o que me possibilita manter o padrão para as recursões.